# Pythonnet cannot convert object to target type

Tags: python, c#, python.net

Using [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) I am calling a Python function, which returns an object, from my C# script. Once I get the result from Python function I want to be able to cast/convert this Python object into C# user defined class. I tried using `AsManagedObject (Type t)` and `As<T> ()` functions but during runtime I got an error -

> Cannot convert object to target type
> Inner Exception PythonException: 'Result' value cannot be converted to Models.Result

I could use some help to convert PyObjects to C# user defined types.

Python -

```
#Result.py
class Result:
    def __init__(self, Sum) -> None:
        self.Sum = Sum

#Main.py
from Result import Result
def add(inputCsharp) -> Result:
     result = Result(inputCsharp.Input1 + inputCsharp/input2)
     return result
```

C# -

```
//Result.cs
public class Result
{
    public int Sum { get; set; }
}

//Program.cs
using (Py.GIL())
{
    using (var scope = Py.CreateScope())
    {
        dynamic obj = Py.Import(@"Main");

        var inputCsharp = new Input() 
        {
            Input1 = 2,
            Input2 = 3
        };
       
        var result = obj.add(inputCsharp.ToPython());
        var t = (Result)result.AsManagedObject(typeof(Result)); //here it is throwing an error
    }
}
```